# How to Generate Sequential Coupon Codes

Tags: magento-1.9, coupon, coupon-codes

I have a client who wishes to generate 10,000 sequential coupon codes.  I don't think this is possible in Magento.  Probably due to the risk it would cause by enabling people to guess coupon codes.

Anyway, I have explained this but they still want to have them as this is the only way the printing company they have chosen can print them!

Is there anyway in Magento to generate sequential coupon codes?  Perhaps there is a module available or simple code change to do this?

I would prefer to convince them to use a better printing company but am curious to see if it's possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think i have solution four your problem .
See image , i suggest some magento rule , if you need further customization then we need to do it for you . Tell me for further.

[image]
[image]